# session error when using multiple uwsgi worker and beaker session.typ is memory

Tags: session, uwsgi

i'm running a pyramid webapp, using velruse to make OAuth. if running the app alone, it succeeded.
but if running with uwsgi multiple and set session.type = memory.
request.session  will not contain necessary token info when callback from oauth.

## production.ini:

```
session.type = memory
session.data_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/data
session.lock_dir = %(here)s/data/sessions/lock
session.key = mykey
session.secret = mysecret

[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:6543
master = true
workers = 8
max-requests = 65536
debug = false
autoload = true
virtualenv = /home/myname/my_env
pidfile = ./uwsgi.pid
daemonize = ./mypyramid-uwsgi.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use memory as session store only the worker in which the session data has been written will be able to use that infos. You should use another sessione store (that can be shared by all of the workers/processes)

Answer (score 0):

your uWSGI config is not clear (it looks like it only contains the socket option). Can you re-paste it ?